# Why in this case order of conditions matter?

Tags: javascript

**Hi everyone**

First of all sorry for the dumb question.

I'm a newbie and can't really figure out by myself why in this case (in this particular order)

```js
const recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};

function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  if(prop !== 'tracks' && value) {
    records[id][prop] = value
  } else if (prop === 'tracks' && !records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    records[id][prop] = [value]
  } else if (prop === 'tracks' && records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    records[id][prop].push(value)
  } else if (!value) {
    delete records[id][prop]
  }

  return records
}
console.log(updateRecords(recordCollection, 2548, "tracks", ""))
```

condition

```
else if (!value) {
  delete records[id][prop]
}
```

will not work as expected (is not deleting 'tracks' property) until being swapped with

```
else if (prop === 'tracks' && records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  records[id][prop].push(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when `prop` is `'tracks'` one of the following two conditions
will always be `true`

```
} else if (prop === 'tracks' && !records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  records[id][prop] = [value]
} else if (prop === 'tracks' && records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  records[id][prop].push(value)
}
```

Because `!records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)` is a negation of `records[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)`, which means when `prop === 'tracks'` is `true`, one of the above `else if`s will also be `true`, thus always skipping *all* `else if` checks (and blocks) that follow them (*and* the `else` block, but here it is not present).

Additionally, it is important to keep in mind that boolean expressions and thus also checks in `if`/`else if` statements [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in many programming languages, which means that the checks are done in order and as soon as one condition is `true` its block is executed and all remaining checks are skipped (they are not even attempted). Only in the case when all conditions would return `false`, only then all conditions would have been fully evaluated.